# Is the Facebook "Share" button being deprecated?

Tags: facebook

I have a business requirement to add a Share on Facebook button to a site. There are a lot of links on the web that point to [this page](http://www.facebook.com/facebook-widgets/share.php) but that just points to [the page about the like button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/). Considering there really isn't any talk of a Share button on that page, makes me think it's going away.

[This blog post from 2009](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/323) talks about the Share button. I didn't see, when I searched, any mention about the Share button being phased out.

I'm unclear on whether I should implement this with sharer.php or whether I should tell the business that "Share" is on the way out and we should just implement "Like".

I have seen [some](http://www.barbariangroup.com/posts/7544-the_facebook_share_button_has_been_deprecated_called_it) [blog](http://mashable.com/2011/02/27/facebook-like-button-takes-over-share-button-functionality/) posts that suggest Share is deprecated, but nothing official from Facebook.

Comment: Looks like they've update the documentation on the sharer button page to indicate it is officially not supported and has been deprecated.  See my answer I added below.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is not deprecated per se, but we do want developers to move the Like button.

Comment: Sweet, a real Facebook person. Thanks for dropping in.

Comment: Might not have been official deprecated at the time Douglas posted, but has been since. See FB QA's reason for closing this bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/252983554810810/

Comment: The like button is horrible and doesn't integrate in the design, why do FB want people to use that and break their design?

Answer (score 9):

Official word from Facebook on the sharer.php being deprecated and not supported: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/

> The Share button has been deprecated in favor of the Like button, and will no longer be supported. Please use the Like button whenever possible to drive maximum traffic to your apps.

Comment: That link now just redirects to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/ where there is no mention of share/sharer.php - However, there is now mention of it here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ under 'What happened to the old Share button?'

Comment: Looks like it's back actually:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/share-links/

Answer (score 4):

2014: The sharer.php has been well..undeprecated. It figures, as this method has been used on millions of sites and was still being used even when the docs were previously saying that it was deprecated. Links in the old format will use the new share button functionality:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/

> *This new Share Button works with a new version of our web-based Share Dialog. When using the sharer.php method of invoking the Share Dialog, this dialog will also display the new version without any changes required.*

And:

> ***Can I use the Share Dialog without using the Share Button?**
>   Yes, although we recommend using the Share button to offer the
>   simplest and most consistent experience for people using your site,
>   you can invoke the Share Dialog using a link:*

Answer (score 3):

I believe it has been deprecated in favor of an improved Like button that has similar functionality. The language can be tweaked to 'Recommend', but I found these articles when doing similar research.

http://mashable.com/2011/02/27/facebook-like-button-takes-over-share-button-functionality/

http://visiblefactors.com/blog/994-facebook-likes-meta-data-thumbnails/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Source? That is actually from FB? The first link in your post is in my OP.

Comment: Sorry dude, you're right! I clicked on the first link ('some') but not the second ('blog'). Our developers are taking that route, and it seems to be the consensus, but Facebook's own documentation is so poor that there I've never seen anything official.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of any plans to deprecate the share bookmarklet (which is `sharer.php`). The deprecation I think you're thinking of is the deprecation of the `<fb:share>` tag, an XFBML tag which basically did the same thing as `<fb:like>` before `<fb:like>` came into existence. Now, they're redundant, so I think `<fb:share>` is gradually being phased out.

Comment: The two blog posts that I linked tell me that sharer.php IS being phased out.

Comment: We're talking about different share buttons: I'm talking about the share functionality in the bookmarklet, and the blog post you link is talking about the XFBML tag.

Comment: But the share.php widgets page (which was supposed to talk about sharer.php) is redirecting to the like page.

Comment: I don't believe it was; I believe that was talking about the `<fb:share>` tag.

Comment: I think you should skim that blog post then click on the "Facebook Share" link near the top.

Comment: I did, I saw the link redirecting. You're talking about the button that looks [like this](http://www.xyzsongs.com/images/facebook_share.png), right? I'm pretty sure that's the widget. The bookmarklet [is this](http://www.facebook.com/share_options.php). I see no reference to `sharer.php` in that blog post - it's possible that the widget invokes the same page as the bookmarklet, but what I'm saying is that the widget is the only thing phased out, not the concept of sharing.

Comment: Facebook doesn't want you to be limited to sharing stuff only from items with Like buttons, they wouldn't phase everything out.

Answer (score 3):

Using the Like button is probably the right way to go in most cases, but if you don't want to make an app id and want a simple quick method, just do this:

```html
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=yoursite.com', 'sharer', 'width=626,height=436'); return false;">Share on Facebook</a>
```

You can replace the Share on Facebook with an image or whatever you want. Facebook docs reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/share-links/