# Facebook sharer.php default the "who can see it" dropdown

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer

I'm using something like:

```
http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://www.google.com
```

to share Facebook Pages. This outputs [as follows](http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://www.google.com).

Is there a parameter I can add to sharer.php in order to default the "who can see it" dropdown (on the top right) to Public?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sharer.php is being deprecated and you should use the like social plugin See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

**EDIT**

Official word from Facebook on the sharer.php being deprecated and not supported:  http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/

> The Share button has been deprecated in favor of the Like button, and
>   will no longer be supported.
>
> Please use the Like button whenever possible to drive maximum traffic
>   to your apps.

Comment: It is not deprecated per se, see: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7224409/218591). Unfortunately the Like Social plugin does not provide the same functionality, so I'm still looking for an answer to my question.

Comment: Thanks. I'll use Facebook's Feed Dialog.